# The proper place to add try-catch C#

Tags: c#, try-catch

I want to use `try-catch` to check being divided by 0 in

```
((double)o.Close - (double)subList.Skip(idx - t + 1).First().Close) / 
 (double)subList.Skip(idx - t + 1).First().Close
```

...but I don't know where to add `try-catch`. I try to add including the whole `var newList =`, but it is not allowed, since variable `newList` no longer exists later. So where is the proper position to add `try-catch`?

```
var newList = data.GroupBy(o => o.Date).Where(o => o.Key <= Beginday).OrderByDescending(o => o.Key).Take(Y).SelectMany(o => o).GroupBy(x => new { x.Symbol })
                .Select
                (
                    x =>
                    {
                        var subList = x.OrderBy(y => y.Date).ToList();
                        return subList.Select((y, idx) =>
                        {
                            return new
                            {
                                Symbol = y.Symbol,
                                Close = y.Close,
                                Date = y.Date,
                                Vol = (idx < t - 1) ? 0 : new DescriptiveStatistics(subList.Skip(idx - t + 1).Take(t)
                                .Select(o =>
                                ((double)o.Close - (double)subList.Skip(idx - t + 1).First().Close) / (double)subList.Skip(idx - t + 1).First().Close).ToList()).StandardDeviation,                              
                        };
                        });
                    }
                )
                .SelectMany(x => x)
                .ToList();
```

Comment: You cannot put a try..catch inside a linq query. You v=can only do a test to see if you are going to do a dived by zero and then give it a zero (or -1) value inside the query.

Comment: You really should check the denominator first. Don't use try-catch for expected behavior.

Comment: @ Van does that mean everything in the linq query couldn't be try-catch even the temporary variable？

Answer (score 0):

depends on what you're going to do in your catch - if you want newList to have a valid value even if the divisor is 0 then you should probably have your 0 check integrated into the main code flow rather than using exceptional flows.

However, to directly answer your question as written, explicity declare newList to a default value first, then reassign within a try/catch block (place the entirety of the code you've written inside the try, with the explicit default declaration before the try). Then newList will exist when you need to use it later.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to catch everything then

```
        try
          {
            var newList = data.GroupBy(o => o.Date).Where(o => o.Key <=                      Beginday).OrderByDescending(o => o.Key).Take(Y).SelectMany(o => o).GroupBy(x => new { x.Symbol })
            .Select
            (
                x =>
                {
                    var subList = x.OrderBy(y => y.Date).ToList();
                    return subList.Select((y, idx) =>
                    {
                        return new
                        {
                            Symbol = y.Symbol,
                            Close = y.Close,
                            Date = y.Date,
                            Vol = (idx < t - 1) ? 0 : new DescriptiveStatistics(subList.Skip(idx - t + 1).Take(t)
                            .Select(o =>
                            ((double)o.Close - (double)subList.Skip(idx - t + 1).First().Close) / (double)subList.Skip(idx - t + 1).First().Close).ToList()).StandardDeviation,                              
                    };
                    });
                }
            )
            .SelectMany(x => x)
            .ToList();    

            }

     catch(Exception ex)
     {
     //your error
      }
```

Comment: but we will use `newList` later, this way is not allowed, and `newList` is a `anonymous class`, cann't be created before

Comment: @A.Oreo I would assume the code that uses `newList` assumes an exception wasn't thrown when `newList` was created, so the following code should be inside the try-catch as well, or in a separate method.

Comment: I agree with @Rob

Comment: @A.Oreo but btw what error are you getting if you put the try before the newList?

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly do this:

```
var newList = new[]
{
    new { Symbol = "", Close = 0.0, Date = DateTime.Now, Vol = 0 }
}.Take(0).ToList();

try
{
    var newList = data.GroupBy(o => o.Date).Where(o => o.Key <= Beginday).OrderByDescending(o => o.Key).Take(Y).SelectMany(o => o).GroupBy(x => new { x.Symbol })
        .Select
        (
            x =>
            {
                var subList = x.OrderBy(y => y.Date).ToList();
                return subList.Select((y, idx) =>
                {
                    return new
                    {
                        Symbol = y.Symbol,
                        Close = y.Close,
                        Date = y.Date,
                        Vol = (idx < t - 1) ? 0 : new DescriptiveStatistics(subList.Skip(idx - t + 1).Take(t)
                        .Select(o =>
                        ((double)o.Close - (double)subList.Skip(idx - t + 1).First().Close) / (double)subList.Skip(idx - t + 1).First().Close).ToList()).StandardDeviation,                              
                };
                });
            }
        )
        .SelectMany(x => x)
        .ToList();    
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

So long as the names and types are the same in the two anonymous types then this works fine.

Comment: Yeah, that is one of the solution, is it possible to `try-catch` `Vol =` directly in the `return`, does that mean everything in the `linq query` couldn't be `try-catch` even the temporary variable？

Comment: @A.Oreo - In every spot that you have a `return` statement you could include a `try`/`catch`. In fact, that would be preferred over catching on the entire LINQ query.